# What causes ruins rubble to fall in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Ruins Rubble (the recallable rocks that fall from the sky islands) seem to fall at random times in somewhat random places. What rules govern the appearance and fall of these objects?

Comment: Have you checked if there's a floating island above?

Comment: Yes, and there usually is, but often multiple ruins rubble fall in the same area with delays between each other. If they fell the moment they spawned in, the ruins rubble would all fall at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these are scripted for specific locations with multiple chunks having specific delays.

Recalling a lot of this rubble will take you to a floating island above, but there are some that don't seem to be connected to anything and just exist to take you upwards.

For cases where there's multiple rubble coming off of a single island, the delay between chunks seems to be predetermined.

While I was doing the Goron quest, I started walking down the path from Goron City to the top of Death Mountain three times before getting distracted by something else further down the mountain, making me teleport back up to avoid climbing. Each time I got near the ruins right above the hot springs nearby, one chunk would fall in the water, then a few seconds later a second chunk fell, then a third a bit after. The positions were all exactly the same each time I passed through this area and with the same delay between each.